# NodeJS. Express 4. How to define environment

Tags: node.js, express

How can i define enviroment at NodeJS, Express4?

Don't work. Output error in console.

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

EDIT:

http://rghost.net/57634264/image.png

"NODE_ENV" is unknown command.

Comment: It's hart to help without knowing the error, your code, or anything else about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because windows CMD is a lot different than POSIX-like shells (used in linux and osx), which is what most of the tutorials and documentation for node userland is written for.

I recommend either using the Git Bash terminal that comes with [git(link)](http://git-scm.com/) to get a POSIX-like shell, or use the windows command to set the variable (takes two commands):

```
set NODE_ENV=production
node app.js
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [express 4 documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings):

> settings
>
> The following settings will alter how Express behaves:
>
> - env Environment mode, defaults to process.env.NODE_ENV (NODE_ENV environment variable) or "development"

Start your app with the command you posted:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

If you've used express correctly (can't tell here as you've not posted code), you can access `NODE_ENV` through the `app.get()` method, which, in this context, will get the setting variable.

```
if (app.get('env') == 'production') { 
  // do something only production does
}
```

Comment: Image with Error: [http://rghost.net/57634264/image.png](http://rghost.net/57634264/image.png)

Error translate: "NODE_ENV" is unknown command.